# Smart pointers and polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I implemented reference counting pointers (called `SP` in the example) and I'm having problems with polymorphism which I think I shouldn't have.

In the following code:

```
    SP<BaseClass> foo()
    {   
        // Some logic...
        SP<DerivedClass> retPtr = new DerivedClass();
        return retPtr;
    }
```

`DerivedClass` inherits from `BaseClass`.  With normal pointers this should have worked, but with the smart pointers it says `"cannot convert from 'SP<T>' to 'const SP<T>&"` and I think it refers to the copy constructor of the smart pointer.

How do I allow this kind of polymorphism with reference counting pointer? 
I'd appreciate code samples cause obviously im doing something wrong here if I'm having this problem.

**PS:** Please don't tell me to use standard library with smart pointers because that's impossible at this moment.

Comment: Please post the code for the copy constructor.

Comment: When reading template error messages, it is important to notice what the `T` mean in each position. The error probably said something like cannot convert from `SP<T> with [T = DerivedClass] to const SP<T> & with [T=BaseClass]` that extra piece of information is half of the way to the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Fairly obvious:

```
SP<DerivedClass> retPtr = new DerivedClass();
```

should be:

```
SP<BaseClass> retPtr = new DerivedClass();
```

Comment: Converting SP<DerivedClass> into SP<BaseClass> should be no problem with a good smart pointer implementation.

Comment: This fixes the specific problem in `foo()`, but it does not make for a natural syntax in other places where the conversion may be needed.

Comment: @Danvil: Converting isn't the issue, you can't change the return type in an overloaded function except in limited cases (covariant references and pointers) so it's pointless to even create an `SP` of the wrong type. This answer is the simplest: create an object of the type actually being returned.

Answer (score 4):

You should add implicit converting constructor for `SP<T>`:

```
template<class T>
struct SP {
   /// ......
   template<class Y>
   SP( SP <Y> const & r )
    : px( r.px ) // ...
    {
    }

   //....
private:
   T * px;
}
```

Comment: A template constructor is never a copy constructor. A copy constructor isn't going to help; this is a non-explicit converting constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a template assignment operator:

```
template <class Base>
class SP
{
    ...

    template<class Derived>
    operator = (SP<Derived>& rhs)
    {
        ...
```

(and maybe copy constructor, too)?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the copy constructor:

```
SP(const SP<T>& ref);
```

you need a conversion constructor:

```
template<typename T2>
SP(const SP<T2>& ref);
```

Otherwise, the compiler will not know how to construct `SP<BaseClass>` from a `SP<DerivedClass>`; for him, they are unrelated.

The conversion constructor is fairly trivial, since internally you can convert `*DerivedClass` to `*BaseClass` automatically. Code may be very similar to that for the copy constructor.