# Polymorphism with smart pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I've searched SO a bit but couldn't find anything that answers correctly my problem (I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762176/c11-smart-pointers-and-polymorphism), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682557/smart-pointers-and-polymorphism) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870489/virtual-constructor-idiom-with-smart-pointers) )

I'm currently trying to use smart pointers with polymorphism.

When I try to create a smart pointer to an abstract class with a pointer to an implementation, i.e. :

```
std::shared_ptr<Abstract> ptr = std::make_shared(new Implementation);
```

My compiler (MSVC2012) displays errors about creating an instance of `Abstract` which is not possible because it has pure virtual, even though I try to create a pointer to `Implementation`.

I might just use smart pointers completely wrong in this case, but then I don't know what I did wrong (and Visual Studio doesn't underline the line I mentionned).

I wonder then if it is possible to use smart pointers when polymorphism is needed, and if yes, how it must be done.

Note : I know about covariance, and the fact that shared_ptr is **not** a type that inherit shared_ptr, but thought smart pointers would handle this.

EDIT :

As requested, the real line of code is :

```
std::shared_ptr<ISpectrometer> ret = std::make_shared<OOSpectrometer>(m_spectroWrapper);
```

With `OOSpectrometer` that inherit from the abstract class `ISpectrometer` (and m_spectroWrapper a simple parameter).

The error MSVC gives me (it's in french, so that could be different from the english message) is

```
error C2259: OOSpectrometer : can't instantiate an abstract class due to the following members :
```

And then it lists the pure virtual functions that are in `ISpectrometer` .

Comment: That should work, if `Implementation` derives from `Abstract`. Can you show the real code?

Comment: And can you post the full error?

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/h4hBxQ), for instance, works fine

Comment: Suspect that `OOSpectrometer` is not implementing all pure virtual functions declared in `ISpectrometer`, which means it is abstract. Can you post the interfaces for both?

Comment: You should show The Real Code, or a portion of it that does represent it meaningfully with respect to the error you are getting. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `shared_ptr`. As previously guessed, `OOSpectrometer` is not providing a defintion for the pure virtual functions declared in its base.

Comment: @ALL Right, I completely missed that the source of the error could come from the implementation (well, missing in this case) of `OOSpectrometer`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not with any broken behavior of `std::shared_ptr` with respect to polymorphism, and this error message is pretty clear:

> error C2259: `OOSpectrometer` : can't instantiate an abstract class due to the following members :

Your class `OOSpectrometer` cannot be instantiated because it is abstract. Most likely, it does not implement all the pure virtual functions defined in the `ISpectrometer` interface.

Also, the list of pure virtual member functions which are not overridden by `OOSpectrometer` should be part of the error message your are getting ("*due to the following members: ...*").

Comment: @JBL: Don't worry, happens to everyone ;)

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, the problem is that `OOSpectrometer` is still abstract, not that it's trying to instantiate the abstract base class.

Check that you've correctly overridden all the pure virtual functions declared in `ISpectrometer`; especially the ones listed in the error message.

Comment: Same, you're right and I'm an idiot. Didn't checked that ALL the pure virtual were instantiated, and kept checking the problem with the base class...